# Why are some of the maven dependencies shown in color and do not get resolved?

Tags: maven, dependencies

Just wanted to add couple of dependencies in Maven using Eclipse. Althought some got added correctly some are shown in grey color and does nt get solved[image]

Comment: This is whatI get when try to fix using eclipse 'fix project setup' ........                   No proposals have been found to fix the unresolved reference to 'cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber'.

Comment: have you tried to install it manually with maven? `mvn install` cmd

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same issue in Eclipse Photon. Once I have opened the same project in Eclipse Oxygen it is working fine. I don't know the root cause of this issue but Eclipse Oxygen fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is a problem of scope. For example, let's suppose you want to get a dependency for "REST Assured"... The Maven Repository will give show you a maven sample like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
    <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

If you install this dependency with a "test" **scope**, the .jar files of the dependency will be dark and you can not import them, just like you described:

[image: Dark jars...]

So, if you want to use the dependency at runtime (I mean make the imports and call the proper classes in your code), you should type "compile" instead "test" on scope tag. It would be like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
    <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.2</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Then finally you may have something like this:

[image: The .jar files are "fine" now]

So, I would recommend you to check the scope of your dependencies in your .pom file.

Hope it helps.